# Identify microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, identification

I disassembled a semaphore which I bought in the shop [Flying Tiger](https://eu.flyingtiger.com/products/traffic-light-3003535)

And I found this microcontroller:

[image]

And this is the board schematic:

[image]

I think that it's a SOP236 and some kind of PIC or Attiny, as the GND and VCC pins fit with the schematic.

But I'm not able to find from the code that it's printed on the component "_62B40". I checked multiple sites and databases and had no luck.

Any way to identify this little guy?

My idea is overwrite the code on it, to change the traffic light behaviour.

---

I previously showed a PIC10F200-IOT on the schematic but that was just an example part. The actual part is unknown.

Comment: Maybe it is not a microcontroller, neither reprogrammable... just alternating semaphore lights, this is not so complex in a way that would need a uC. It could use just an oscillator and some flip-flops counting the clock output...

Comment: Luis - Hi, It's not relevant to the IC identification, but FYI the two LEDs connected to IC pins 1 & 3 are the wrong way round on the [current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8TZW.png) schematic. They are shown with their cathodes connected to the positive supply rail.

Comment: Luis, if you update your schematic for any reason, please don't put your PIC IC part number back into it, which I've taken out.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the feedback and for the answers.

Comment: PMS150 is another candidate, I'm not sure what markings that has but the pinout matches and the price is right.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a toy. It will be designed to have minimal BOM.

It could easily be an ASIC or a factory programmed (house-numbered) OTP (**O**ne-**T**ime **P**rogrammable) MCU such as Padauk's (in)famous PTB150 $0.03 MCU or similar parts from makers such as Shenzhen Yspring. Most makers who have 6 pin MCUs have chosen the same Vdd/Vss pins so that's not much of a tell. I doubt it is an expensive part such as Atmel or Microchip. If there are no programming pads it may have been ordered programmed from their supplier.

If you want to reprogram something, maybe splurge the $1 for a part you have access to datasheets etc. on (and a programming tool for).

Comment: I know that the easiest way is using my own parts. Just wanted to know if by any chance I could do something with that component. I'll dismiss that option.
Thanks for the info